# CakePHP3: modify entity on all reads

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have hard time figuring out the best approach to my problem. I have two fields in my `files` model, e.g. `file_path` and `file_name`. Whenever a `file_name` field is read (no matter if it's called via `get()`, `find()`, whether it's JSON or a regular view) I would like it to be modified and return a concatanation of both fields (`$file_name = $file_path .'/'.$file_name`).

I would like to do this in one place to make the code DRY. I figured one way to do this would be an accessor method of an entity as specified in the documentation but accessors only work when the entity is accessed via the object notation and they are not working with `find()`).

Is there any way of doing this transparently in one place (preferably a model)? I was looking into model events, but couldn't figure out which event would be useful in my situation (it looks like I'd need something like afterRead...)

This is what I have tried but it's not working with finders:

```
namespace App\Model\Entity;
use Cake\ORM\Entity;

class File extends Entity
{
    protected function _getFileName($f)
    {
        return $this->file_path.''.$f;
    }
}
```

Comment: Entities don't have a `find()` method. Are you referring to the `find()` method on a query?

Comment: Yes, I'm doing find() in the controller and would like find() to return a modified entity. I can do this modification in a controller after grabbing the result set, but I was thinking of a global mechanism that would allow me to modify the result set 'before' it gets handed over to the controller. Another example: imagine you have 'name' field in 'people' table. Everytime you're grabbing this field (no matter in what controller) you want to add 'Mr.' prefix to it's value.

Comment: I believe I've found the solution here: https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/2768#issuecomment-34038101 It involves using beforeFind() event and $query->formatResults with $results closure. I'll do the tests and post the answer later, unless anybody else wants to do this... It's kind of funny though that you can use beforeFind event to modify data after the find :)

Answer (score 2):

You've added a method to your entity named `_getFileName($f)` and it's going to mutate your data. It doesn't do what you think it does.

From the CakePHP manual on Accessors and Mutators:

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#accessors-mutators

> Accessors will be used when saving entities, so be careful when defining methods that format data, as the formatted data will be persisted.

So when you save your entity the `file_name` field is going to be saved as `$this->file_path.''.$f` and it's going to happen every time you save it.

This is a very confusing issue for most CakePHP developers. I'll give you a quick explanation of those methods.

`function _getXXXX()` returns the value to be **saved** in the database. When you return a *different* value. It means the value stored in the entity object isn't what you want stored in the database. This can trick people, because they see the *updated* value in the views. So they think it's used for formatting.

`function _setXXXX()` returns the value to be **assigned** to the entity object. When you do this `$entity->title = 'FooBar';` the entity will call `_setTitle("FooBar")` and use the returned value as the `title` value assigned to the entity. Again, this will be **saved** in the database.

You see. Both methods change what is stored in the database.

### Use a function

What I do is keep it dead simple.

```
public function getFullFileName() {
     return $this->file_path.' '.$this->file_name;
}
```

In your views just call the function `echo $entity->getFullFileName()`.

### Support serialization

If you need a custom property used for serialization (i.e. JSON). The above function approach won't work. You need to use the [virtual properties](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#creating-virtual-properties) method and use a **different** field name. The key here is that the virtual property does not collide with any table columns.

```
class Document extends Entity {
     protected $_virtual = ['full_path'];

     public function _getFullPath() {
           return $this->file_path.' '.$this->file_name;
     }
 }
```

So in the above example we are using an *Accessor* function. We also added this *new* field name to `$_virtual` so that CakePHP knows to include in JSON output. Since there are no columns in the table schema named `full_path` it won't be persisted to the database.

Comment: Thank you @cgTag, I really appreciate your detailed answer! However: if I use the function approach, I'll have to modify lots of views and like you said this solution won't cut it for JSON data. The closest is probably using virtual properties but according to the Book (and my tests): 'bear in mind that virtual properties cannot be used in finds' so It's the same as with accessors and I'm back where I was.

Comment: Neither accessors or virtual properties can be used in finds. I'm not sure by what you mean by using find. Do you mean using an alias field in your SQL query?

Comment: if you define a virtual property 'foo' and do `$this->Model->find()` in the controller, the virtual property will not show up in the result set returned by the finder.

Comment: it's *virtual* so it's not support to be in the results. It's a *fake* property.

Comment: The virtual property won't be in the results returned by the finder, but as long as you're using hydration (and therefore getting entities instead of arrays), it will be able to recalculate it on the fly whenever you reference it. In other words, `foo` won't be in the list of properties of `$entity`, but `$entity->foo` will give you the expected result regardless.